# How I can fix Extra Argument In call?

Tags: json, swift, weather

I am writing WeatherApp on Swift. I have problem with compilation which called "Extra argument in call".
I am writing HourlyForecast and u can see there my code:

View Controller:

```
HourlyForecast.downloadDailyForecastWeather { (hourlyForecastArray) in
    for data in hourlyForecastArray {
        print("forecast data: \(data.temp, data.date)")
    }
}
```

Part of HourlyForecast.swift:

```
init(weatherDictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
    let json = JSON(weatherDictionary)
    self._temp = json["temp"].double
    self._date = currentDateFromUnix(unixDate: json["ts"].double!)
    self._weatherIcon = json["weather"]["icon"].stringValue
}
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: what method call are you referring to? On another note, I recommend you look into the `Codable` protocol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to *interpolate* each variable separately

```
for data in hourlyForecastArray {
    print("forecast data: \(data.temp), \(data.date)") 
}
```

Notes:

- Don't use *objective-c-ish* variable names with leading underscore.
- In Swift JSON dictionary values are `Any` not `AnyObject`.
- Use `Codable`, it's much more efficient than SwiftyJSON.